# Getting first key of an object?

Tags: javascript

I have an array here and I have duplicated objects(?) whatever, and i want to console log only one of them based on nick instead both of them.
How do I do that?

**Snippet:**

```js
var _hero = [{
  nick: "Mike",
  lvl: 500,
  x: 10,
  y: 10
}, {
  nick: "Mike",
  lvl: 500,
  x: 10,
  y: 10
}]
let main = () => {
  _hero.forEach(function(_hero) {
    if (_hero.nick == "Mike") {
      console.log(_hero);
    }
  });
};
main();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to clarify, are you asking how to find the first object in the array that matches a condition (in this case the first object that has `nick == "Mike"`)?

If that is the case, you can use JavaScript's [`Array.find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) function that makes this a breeze.

```
const hero = _hero.find(hero => hero.nick === "Mike")
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have multiple heros here and you want one of each you would need to deduplicate your array. You can do this by searching through all indices before a given index, or keeping a dictionary of seen values and checking if you've already seen that hero. Take a look at [Remove duplicate values from JS array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9229645/remove-duplicate-values-from-js-array)

Comment: I dont really want to remove dublicate values. All i want to archive is to pick only first object(?) without changing the array pretty much. I've updated my question, maybe it's much cleaner now.